# Carousel images don't stack

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to have a component with carousel inside.

```
 <ngb-carousel>
  <template ngbSlide>
    <img src="img1" alt="Random first slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>First slide label</h3>
      <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
    </div>
  </template>
  <template ngbSlide>
    <img src="img2" alt="Random second slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Second slide label</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </template>
  <template ngbSlide>
    <img src="img3" alt="Random third slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Third slide label</h3>
      <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
    </div>
  </template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

This is my component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@Component({
  selector: 'img-carousel',
  templateUrl: './img-carousel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./img-carousel.component.scss']
})
export class ImgCarouselComponent {
}
```

And this is the module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { BookingComponent }   from './booking.component';
import { ImgCarouselComponent } from './img-carousel/img-carousel.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [NgbModule.forRoot()],
    exports: [BookingComponent],
    declarations: [BookingComponent, ImgCarouselComponent],
    providers: [],
})

export class BookingModule { }
```

The problem is that the images are not stacked. Do I need to import something more, or am I missing something essential?

Angular Version : 2.0.2
ng-bootstrap: @latest

I am using Angular-cli without system.js.

Comment: I have found the issue. I was using bootstrap 3 for the rest of my application, but bootstrap 4 is required for this to work.

Hope it helps, as it doesn't error and it fails silently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot work with Bootstrap 3. The problem goes away when you migrate to version 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and added the `cdn` and it worked fine. If you don't want to reference the `cdn` add `bootstrap` to `styles in`.angular-cli.json`.

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well and the cause was that was I trying to pull in the CSS via an invalid path. When I just used the CDN, things worked as expected.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">`